# Change text of a select option while the menu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option menu to use in mobile devices.

And I have my first option with text "- Menu - ", to open my menu.

```
<option value="menu" selected="selected" name="menu">- Menu -</option>
```

But when I open this menu on mobile, I want to change the text of "- Menu - " to "Close Menu".

Im trying like this:

```
$( "#select_menu" ).click(function() {
    $('#select_menu option[value="menu"]').text("Close Menu");
});
```

But its not working fine, because the text " - Menu -" is only changing to "Close Menu" when I close my select option menu.

And when I have my select option menu open I want always to have the text "Close Menu".

And when I close my select option menu I want again text as " - Menu -".

Do you know how can I do this?

```
<select id="select_menu"> 
    <option value="menu" selected="selected">- Menu -</option>
    <option value="/team"> Team </option> 
    <option value="/contacts"> Contacts</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Try value as empty or just select the first element

Comment: I don't know how your code is working at all, as you are selecting an element with a `value` of `menu`, which does not exist. I think you want to select a `name` of `menu` instead.

Comment: heres example http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4sxf1L8k/ used `[name="menu"]`

Comment: Thanks I forgot "menu" in my question. But I have correct in my example. And its not working as I want...

Comment: If you test on your mobile devices, you see that when you click in "- Menu -" the select option menu opens with text "-  Menu -", and only when you close menu the text changes to "Close Menu"...

Answer (score 1):

The elements value of menu is "" try this...

```
 $( "#select_menu" ).click(function() {
        $('#select_menu option[value=""]').text("Close Menu");
    });
```

I would also move to this syntax

```
 $( "#select_menu" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
        $(e.target).find( 'option[value=""]').text("Close Menu");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it works like my attempt. 
If you try on your phone when you click on "- Menu -" to open the menu, the menu opens with a menu option like "- Menu -" and
only when you leave the menu the text changes to "Close Menu". But when I close the menu I want again "- Menu -".

Comment: Added just another event for when its changed.. this is ugly code but will work I'd try to isolate the behavior and make it more generic http://jsfiddle.net/xdc5hzar/

Comment: Thanksk for your help really! But the problem still remains. When I click in my option "- Menu -" my select option opens and inside my select option still appears "- Menu -" and not "Close Menu"..

Comment: The fiddle I posted works fine for me? Not sure what you mean. When I click on the select the text changes to "Close Menu" and when you select an option it changes it back to "Menu"

Comment: Your fiddle works fine on desktop but in mobile devices its not working. Maybe for mobile its impossible do this or must be with other method..